# How to put for loop in HTML string

Tags: javascript

```
if (splitsCity.length > 1) {
  row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = '<div class="dropdown">' +
    '<button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="cityDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"' +
    'aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">View</button>' +
    '<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="cityDropdown">'
  for (k = 0; k <= splitsCity.length; k++) {
    '<a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">' + splitsCity[k] + '</a>'
  }
  '</div>' +
  '</div>'
}
```

I need to put for loop in this HTML string.

```
for (k = 0; k <= splitsCity.length; k++) {
  '<a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">' + splitsCity[k] + '</a>'
}
```

If I take For loop like this time that is not performed.
Any suggestion ?

Comment: Can you show us your HTML code? Just minimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the string outside of the if statement and concatenate it within your string.

For example,

```js
let htmlString = ''
for (k = 0; k <= splitsCity.length; k++) {
  htmlString += '<a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">' + splitsCity[k] + '</a>'
}

if (splitsCity.length > 1) {
  row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = 
    '<div class="dropdown">' +
      '<button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="cityDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">View</button>' +
      '<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="cityDropdown">' +
        htmlString +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>'
}
```